# Meteor pass data from client to server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a registration form, and when the user clicks the submit button the value in every textbox will be sent to server to insert that data, and return true/false.

Client:

```
Template.cust_register.events({
    'click button': function(){
          var email = $('#tbxCustEmail').val();
          var msg = $('#tbxCustMsg').val();
          var isSuccess = insertMsg(email,msg);
          if(isSuccess){
             alert("Success");
          }else alert("Try again");
    }
});
```

Server:

```
function insertMsg(email,msg){
     Messages.insert({Email:email,Message:msg});
     return true;
}
```

This turned out to not work.
How to solve this?
Many people said "use publish/subscribe", but I don't understand how to use that.

Comment: You should really study the publish/subscribe model; it's pretty much the basic idea of Meteor and if you don't understand what it means using Meteor is going to be very rough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, watch the [introductory screencast](http://www.meteor.com/screencast) and read the [Data and security](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity) section of the docs.

Your code in a publish/subscribe model would look like this:

*Common:*

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection('messages');
```

*Client:*

```
Meteor.subscribe("messages");

Template.cust_register.events({
    'click button': function(){
          var email = $('#tbxCustEmail').val();
          var msg = $('#tbxCustMsg').val();
          Messages.insert({Email:email,Message:msg});
    }
});
```

*Server:*

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function() {
    return Messages.find();
});
```

Comment: So in Meteor, we can do insert on client side? wow that's dangerous :(

Comment: Read the chapter. After initial prototyping you `meteor remove insecure` and have to define access rules to collections.

Comment: @yozawiratama its not dangerous you use the allow rules to check them before they're inserted on the server its like having permissions

Comment: @yozawiratama u must write some different project with meteor for understand it. It is not dangerous. It is so secure.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution is to use `Meteor.call('yourMethodName')` (on the client).

Then, on the server, you can have

```
Meteor.methods({
    yourMethodName: function() { /* validate input + return some data */ }
});
```

You can consider setting a session variable to the return value.

```
Meteor.call('yourMethodName', function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        Session.set('myData', data);
    } 
});
```

And then in some some template...

```
Template.whatever.helpers({
    messages: function() {
        return Session.get('myData');
    }
});
```

Why do all this?

```
1) You can explicitly deny all direct `insert/update/find` queries from the client, and force usage of pre-defined Meteor methods.

2) You can manually determine when certain data is "refreshed".
```

Obviously, this methodology undermines the value of the subscription/publication model, and it should only be used in cases where real-time data isn't required.