# how to set global variable in routes.js meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using `iron:router` for routing. I need to set the global variable `logintoken` while routing by extracting a route parameter.
I can not use `Session`.

The code I used is:

```
Router.route('/:logintoken',{
    action: function () {
        token_id = this.params.logintoken;
    }
});
```

The server side code is :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {  
    console.log(token_id)    
    return user;
});
```

Comment: @Kyll:  Actually I defined this code in the client side and I am trying to access the token_id in the server side. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @Kyll: Thanks for the edit. Yes I need to send data to the server. I tried to access the token_id directly from server. I have also added my server side code in the question

Comment: @Kyll: As "token_id" is set as global variable. Is it neccessary to pass from client to server

Comment: You seem to lack basic understanding of scopes. "global" means either on the client or the server. You have to pass data to the server for it to be aware of said data.

Comment: @Kyll: k thanks. So is it possible to use Meteor.call in router

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor pass data from client to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630829/meteor-pass-data-from-client-to-server)